# Simplification using Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to simplify the following using Mathematica.

```
simplify[iota * arctan(-iota*x)]
```

This simply yields the expression in mathematical terms.

I want it to be simplified and expressed in terms of hyperbolic function.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica is case sensitive and only uses square brackets for function argument delimiters:
Also the imaginary unit is `I` : fixing all that it works:

```
 Simplify[I ArcTan[-I x]]

 ArcTanh[x]
```

In fact you don't even need the `Simplify`, `ArcTan[-I x]` evaluates to `-I ArcTanh[x]` without `Simplify`